# What kind of matrix structure produces multiple singular values, all of which are of the same magnitude?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For instance, a matrix for a systems of equations that are the same would produce only one singular value. But what kind of system of equations would produces several equal singular values?

Comment: What do you mean by a singular value?

Comment: The entries from the diagonal matrix from SVD.